# ExtJs - File Uploading Error on IE8 + IE9

Tags: php, javascript, extjs4.1

I created a File Upload on the actuall EXTJS version to my Server. If the file is uploaded successfully a json response is created by the backend to process on the frontend. On Chrome and Firefox its working fine, but on IE its allways downloading the json response as file and interrupting so the process, any idea how to prevent this on IE?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

please tell me .What version you are using .I am using extjs 3.4 file upload its working file in all browser.

```
   new Ext.form.FormPanel({

            fileUpload : true,

            items:[new Ext.form.TextField({
                id:"iconUpload",
                fieldLabel: 'Image',
                inputType: 'file',
                name: 'appIcon'

            })],
            listeners : {
                render : function(form){
                }
            },
            buttonAlign: 'center',
            buttons: [{
                text     : 'Submit',
                formBind : true,
                handler  : function(){
                   itemPanel.getForm().submit({
                        waitMsg: "Progress ...",
                        success: function(form, action){

                        },
                        failure: function(form, action){

                        }
                    });

                }
            }]

        });
```

Comment: I am using the newest, 4.2.1.883.

Answer (score 1):

So I found the solution, the problem ist the Content-Type. Normaly I am using a json response, but IE8 and IE9 is having troubles with it, so you have to send a "text/html" content type to fix this problem

Answer (score 0):

MartinMB answer is essentially correct. This answers aims to provide a little bit more background.

[In Ext JS](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.Basic-method-hasUpload), file uploads are not performed using normal 'Ajax' techniques, that is they are not performed using XMLHttpRequests. Instead a hidden  element containing all the fields is created temporarily and submitted with its target set to refer to a dynamically generated, hidden  which is inserted into the document but removed after the return data has been gathered.

The server response is parsed by the browser to create the document for the IFRAME. If the server is using JSON to send the return object, then the `Content-Type` header must be set to `text/html` in order to tell the browser to insert the text unchanged into the document body.

Chrome, FF, IE10 and up do just when when they see `Content-Type` = `application/json` in the response header. However when you do that to IE8 and IE9, when the server reponds from the file upload, you see a message saying something along the lines of: "Do you want to open or save this document"?

So, to fix that in IE8 and IE9, just do `Content-Type` to `text/html` and you're fine. The modern browsers responds just the same, so you're not breaking anything there with that solution.